# solr or alternatives to index xml annotated text files

Tags: search, solr, lucene, hibernate-search

Is it possible to index annotated xml files in lucene and search them in solr?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, if your questions is on weather either Solr or Lucene can parse XML and index it taking into account it's XML structure (making a difference between text for tags and text inside the body of those tags) then the answer is no, they cannot.

What you need to do, if you want to use either of them, is to create your own XML parser, extract the needed data from the XML file, and index it as Lucene or Solr documents. Once you do that, the documents will be searchable on the fields you declared.

I recommend using Solr. It uses a bit more resources than a direct Lucene implementation (a bit more RAM, though all this is configurable in Solr parameters) but is far more easier to develop against as compared to Lucene.

Comment: Just a note: [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/0.7/formats.html#XML_and_derived_formats) is usually recommended for a parser of typical file formats that works well with getting data into lucene.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This wont work for me. I guess that i wont be able to show the context later. If every word become a field, i wont have phrases, paragraphs, textes any more.